# setup.py using requirements.txt with local .whl files

Tags: setup.py, requirements.txt

I am trying to use a `setup.py` file to prepare my environment. I would like to use `.whl` in my `requirements.txt` file to perform python package installs. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: 'code'
# read requirements.txt  and place into install_regs

setup(
        name= package_name,
        version='0.1',
        description='DataTools analytics library',
        author='xxx-xx-datatools',
        author_email='datatools@xxx.com',
        license='MIT',
 long_description=long_description,
        packages=find_packages(exclude=['dev.*','dev','.svn','.idea']),         
        install_requires=install_reqs,
        namespace_packages=['datatools', ],
 )       

with  requirement.txt looking like:
.\datatools\wheels\numpy-1.10.0b1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
'code'

Comment: Add that to your question as an edit.